# Removing a open set from a finite open covering of a Normal space.

Tags: general-topology

Like the title says: ¿The subspace resulting by removing a element of a finite open covering of a normal space $X$, is also normal space?

In symbols: Let $(X,\tau)$ be a normal space and $\{U_1, U_2, \dots, U_n\}$ a finite open covering of $X$. Then the subspace $\bigcup_{i = 1}^{n-1} U_i$ with the restriction of $\tau$ is also normal.

Comment: You are asking whether an open subset of a normal space is still normal...

Comment: Yes @OlivierBégassat

Comment: You will have to look for non-metrizable counter examples.

Comment: So, the statement isn't true for all normal spaces? @OlivierBégassat It is a step in a proof that I'm doing.

Comment: I don't know whether the statement is true or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false. Let $X$ be a countably infinite set and $Y$ an uncountable set, and let $p$ and $q$ be distinct points not in $X\cup Y$. Let $X^*=X\cup\{p\}$ and $Y^*=Y\cup\{q\}$, and topologize $X^*$ and $Y^*$ as follows. Points of $X$ and points of $Y$ are isolated. A set $U\subseteq X^*$ is an open nbhd of $p$ if and only if $p\in U$, and $X\setminus U$ is finite. A set $U\subseteq Y^*$ is an open nbhd of $q$ if and only if $q\in U$, and $Y\setminus U$ is finite. (If you’re familiar with the notion of the one-point compactification of a space, $X^*$ is the one-point compactification of $X$ when $X$ is given the discrete topology, and $Y^*$ is the one-point compactification of $Y$ when $Y$ is given the discrete topology.)

Let $Z=X^*\times Y^*$ with the product topology. $Z$ is the product of two compact Hausdorff spaces, so $Z$ is compact Hausdorff and therefore normal. Let $U=X^*\times Y$ and $V=X\times Y^*$, and let $W$ be any open nbhd of $\langle p,q\rangle$ in $Z$. Clearly $\{U,V,W\}$ is a finite open cover of $Z$.

Now consider $U\cup V=Z\setminus\{\langle p,q\rangle\}$. Let $H=X\times\{q\}$ and $K=\{p\}\times Y$; it’s easy to check that $H$ and $K$ are disjoint closed subsets of $U\cup V$. However, $H$ and $K$ do not have disjoint open nbhds in $U\cup V$, so $U\cup V$ is not normal.

To see this, suppose that $G$ is an open set containing $H$. Then for each $x\in X$ there is a finite $F_x\subseteq Y$ such that $\{x\}\times(Y^*\setminus F_x)\subseteq G$. Let $F=\bigcup_{x\in X}F_x$; $F$ is the union of countably many finite sets, so $F$ is countable, and we can choose a point $y\in Y\setminus F$. But then $X\times\{y\}\subseteq G$, so every open nbhd of $\langle p,y\rangle$ has non-empty intersection with $G$, and it follows immediately that every open nbhd of $K$ has non-empty intersection with $G$.

Normality is a closed-hereditary property: every closed subset of a normal space is normal. Every open subset of a normal space $X$ is normal if and only if $X$ is hereditarily normal; this is equivalent to saying that whenever $A,B\subseteq X$, and $A\cap\operatorname{cl}B=B\cap\operatorname{cl}A=\varnothing$, then there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $A\subseteq U$ and $B\subseteq V$.